# Reading from usb as a comport

Tags: c, bluetooth, serial-port, usb

I'm quite a beginner in the embedded world, since I'm always at the "other side of the wire" as a SW engineer so please don't crucify me for a question that might seem silly.

When I'm working with a Bluetooth device that connects to the computer, it is usually presented as a virtual COM-port which I connect and read the data from using winapi. Now our embedded engineer presented me a device that sends the same data through a USB cable which also presents as a virtual comport at my system which I read the same (meaning, for me it is completely transparent).

Now I wonder, in any other devices that use a USB connection, I don't see the device as a comport (like a mouse, or a keyboard), yet the info is sent. Why there is a need in a comport in this case, and what other reading options available?

Comment: windows, I'm using winapi. Doesn't this matter?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read some [basic USB information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus).

The difference you've noticed is because USB supports something called ["device classes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Device_classes), that basically control how the computer (the host) views the device.

One such class is ["USB communications device"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class) which often becomes a virtual COM port, for instance.

Another is the very commonly seen ["USB mass storage device"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass-storage_device_class) which is what e.g. flash drives use.

A third is the one you mention for mouses and keyboards, which is called ["USB human interface device"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class).

Which class a particular device uses is communicated when it's first connected on the bus, so that the host can load the proper driver. You cannot magically force a device to switch classes, the class is typically a "hard" (non-modifiable) part of the device's implementation, chosen by the designers of the device.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just wanted to make sure I'm not doing something wrong with creating a virtual port when there is no need to do so any more. Thanks for editing as well.